# Python list comprehension conversion

Tags: python, list-comprehension

How would I re-write this function using a list comprehension? The resulting function should only have 2 lines: the definition line and the return line containing a list comprehension expression.

```
def processList(listOfNumbers):
    result = []
    for i in listOfNumbers:
        if i<0:
            result.append(i*i)
        else:
            result.append((i*i)+1)
    return result
```

Comment: What does `i<0 == 0:` mean here? It would be amazing if you could explain what the code is trying to do,

Comment: listOfNumbers is a list of only numbers

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't answer my question, sorry...

Answer (score 1):

You may be trying to do this :

```
def processList(listOfNumbers):
    return [i ** 2 if i < 0 else i ** 2 + 1 for i in listOfNumbers]
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I trying to do. Thanks, I really appreciate your help. I could not figure how to constrain it to just one return line. But now I see, and this also helps me comprehend list comprehensions.